# I want to return data from doInBackground method and compare with other string in other methods

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

what I do in this code for comparing retrieved data from server to other string, please tell me changes.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> matchStudentsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third_sem);
    present = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    bt= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // Call Async task to get the match fixture
    new GetFixture().execute();

}
private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
        Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_Students);
        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_Students,ServiceHandler.GET);
        // print the json response in the log
        Log.d("Get match fixture response: ", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                Log.d("try", "in the try");
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                matchRecords = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_Table);
                Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                int len = matchRecords.length();
                Log.d("len", "get array length");
                for (int i = 0; i <len; i++) {
                    JSONObject c = matchRecords.getJSONObject(i);
                    String RollNo = c.getString(TAG_Roll_No);
                    Log.d("RollNo", RollNo);
                    String FirstName = c.getString(TAG_First_Name);
                    Log.d("FirstName", FirstName);
                    String LastName = c.getString(TAG_Last_Name);
                    Log.d("LastName", LastName);
                    //  hashmap for single match
                    HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_Roll_No, RollNo);
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_First_Name, FirstName);
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_Last_Name, LastName);
                    matchStudentsList.add(matchFixture);


                }



            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        return null;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);




         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ThirdSem.this, matchStudentsList,
                    R.layout.list_checkitem, new String[]{TAG_Roll_No, TAG_First_Name, TAG_Last_Name, TAG_BAddress}
                    , new int[]{R.id.RollNo, R.id.FirstName, R.id.LastName }

        );
            setListAdapter(adapter);

    }


}



}
```

it will be very very helpful for me please

Comment: I see no php here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a null value on all your if statements, you should return matchStudentsList once you are done with your for loop, otherwise return null

after your for loop , add:

`return matchStudentsList;`

and change your `onPostExecute` signature to:

`protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {`

also change your AsyncTask definition to:

`AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>`

Comment: thanx for giving your suggestion to me it is really work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your doInBackground() string by something like this.

```
String desiredString = new GetFixture().execute().get();
```

Call the above in onCreate() method. Instead of :

```
new GetFixture().execute();
```